# RWD - Best way to put related products in the tabs section?

Tags: template

Whats the best way to put the related products in the tab section and make them horizontal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use easytab  extension for Releated Product Tab

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-tabs-2-0-free-magento-extension.html

and install in your template folder.

and configure through admin panel.

Comment: Kinda hoping not to use and extension on this, does anyone know the coding steps?